# Prove $x=\int_{1}^{x}\cos{\frac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln\left(3-\frac{1}{t}\right) \mathrm{d}t $ for some $x>1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

Prove that $$x=\int_{1}^{x}\cos{\frac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln\left(3-\frac{1}{t}\right) \mathrm{d}t $$ for some $x>1.$

The only idea I have is to calculate the derivative of $\int_{1}^{x}\cos{\frac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln\left(3-\frac{1}{t}\right) \ \mathrm{d}t $. First, I let $y=\int_{1}^{x}\cos{\frac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln\left(3-\frac{1}{t}\right) \mathrm{d}t -x$ , then I calculate $y'(x)$ , but $y(x)$ isn't a monotonous function, so I got stuck.

Can anyone help or give me a hint on how to approach this problem?

Thank you very much guys

Comment: Inequality has a root? What does that mean?

Comment: @zhw. It mean always exist at least x>1 satisfy the inequality

Answer (score 3):

At x = 1 then

$$\int_{1}^{x} cos \frac{1}{t} ⋅ ln(3 - \frac{1}{t})dt = 0 \lt x $$

What does the integrand approach as t approaches infinity?

Can you see what the integral approaches in terms of x by considering the graph of this?

The integral is continuous for x $\geq$ 1. Can you see how to prove it from here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $I(x) = \int_1^x \cos(\frac1t) \ln(3 - \frac1t) dt$. As Ben suggested, we will use the intermediate value theorem.

First, $I(1) = 0$. Thus, $I(1) - 1 < 0$.

Then, for $x > 1$ :

$$I(x) = \ln(3) \int_1^x \cos(1/t) dt + \int_1^x \cos(1/t) \ln(1 - 1/3t) dt$$

Both integrals diverge, and the integrand are positive, thus :

$$I(x) = \ln(3) \int_1^x 1 \times dt + o(x) - \int_1^x 1 \times \frac1{3t} dt + o(\ln(x)) = \ln(3) x + o(x) \quad [x \to \infty]$$

Finally :

$$I(x) - x = (\ln(3)-1) x + o(x) \geq 0.005 x + o(x) \to \infty \quad [x \to \infty]$$

Thus, there exist $x_0 > 1$ such that $I(x_0) - x_0 > 0$. Moreover $x \mapsto I(x)$ is continuous (antiderivative of a continous function). The intermediate value theorem gives the existence of $x$ such that $I(x) = x$.

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done numerically.

This is how it looks:

[image: crossing]

The plot shows $x$ and the integral. Blue is the integral calculated numerically and the sand colored graph is $x$.

This solution is graphical methodology, plot and adopted the plot interval. This is done with Mathematica and the built-in NIntegrate with default settings.

In Mathematica a numerical solution input is

```
FindRoot[NIntegrate[Cos[1/t] Log[3 - 1/t], {t, 1, x}] == x, {x, 
   27.22}, AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8][[1, 2]]
```

The output is $27.2244$. This result is properly bigger than one. The difference between x and the integral is smaller and $10^{-8}$ at this point.

At the start the value of the integral is less than $x$. The increase is already faster than $x$. The value of the integral grow faster than x for positive value bigger than 1.

This uses a famous algorithm called fixpoint iteration. The rewrite into the fixpoint form and the iteration are done internally and optimized. This does not find a more exact value than the fiven one. This fixpoint iteration does involve the first derivative.

This is only a numerical prove open to verification. But this verification can only be done numerically or graphically.

Plot of the both function on a larger interval:

[image]

Plot of the crossing of both functions represented by the difference:
[image].

Answer (score 0):

Let's define the function:
$$g(x)=\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t}-x \, , \,\, x \in (1, +\infty)$$

**Step 1**

Notice that
$$
1 \lt t \lt x 
$$

since all members of the inequality are positive, it follows
$$
1 \gt \dfrac{1}{t} \gt \dfrac{1}{x} \iff -1 \lt -\dfrac{1}{t} \lt -\dfrac{1}{x} \iff  2 \lt 3-\dfrac{1}{t} \lt 3-\dfrac{1}{x}
$$

Also, since $1 \gt \frac{1}{t}\gt \frac{1}{x} \gt 0$ , then $\frac{1}{t} \in \left(0, 1\right) \subset \left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ where $\cos{\frac{1}{t}}$
is monotonically decreasing:
$$
\cos{1}\lt\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\lt\cos\dfrac{1}{x}
$$

Since, all members of the above two inequalities are positive, multiplying them leads to:
$$
\cos{1}\cdot\ln{2} \lt \cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)} \lt \cos\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}
$$

Now by integrating over $\, t$ , from $1$ to $x \gt 1$ :
$$
\int_1^x{\cos{1}\cdot\ln{2}\ \mathcal{d}t} \lt \int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} \lt \int_1^x{\cos\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\ \mathcal{d}t}}
$$

Since $x$ is independent of $t$:
$$
\cos{1}\cdot\ln{2}\cdot\int_1^x{1\ \mathcal{d}t} \lt \int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} \lt \cos\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\cdot\int_1^x{1\ \mathcal{d}t}}
$$

Calculating the integrals:
$$
\cos{1}\cdot\ln{2}\cdot(x-1) \lt \int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} \lt \cos\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}\cdot(x-1)
$$

**Step 2**

Now suppose there is some real number $a$ very close to $1^+$ and some finite real number $b$ approaching $+\infty$, such that $x \in [a, b]\subset(1,+\infty)$.

1. Taking the limit as $x\to +\infty$
   $$
   \cos{1}\cdot\ln{2}\cdot\lim_{x\to +\infty}(x-1) \lt \lim_{x\to +\infty}\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} \lt \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\cos\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}\cdot(x-1)\right)
   $$
   Since $\cos{1}\cdot\ln{2}\gt 0$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\cos\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}= \cos{0}\cdot\ln{3}=\ln{3}\gt 0$, this leads to:

$$
\cos{1}\cdot\ln{2}\cdot\lim_{x\to +\infty}(x-1) \lt \lim_{x\to +\infty}\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} \lt \ln{3}\cdot\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(x-1\right)
$$

But $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(x-1\right)=+\infty$ , so:
$$
+\infty\lt \lim_{x\to +\infty}\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} \lt +\infty
$$

The indefinite integral is continuous in $(1,+\infty)$

By the **Squeeze Theorem** it follows that:
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} = +\infty
$$

Because of the above limit that goes to $+\infty$ as $x\to +\infty$ and the fact that $b$ was defined as approaching to $+\infty$ but is a finite real number, this leads to the fact that the integral's limit as $x\to b$ tends to a very large positive real number $\epsilon_{\infty}$ that approaches $+\infty$. So:
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} = +\infty
$$

and $g(b)=\epsilon_\infty$

2. Taking the limit as $x\to 1^+$
   $$
   \cos{1}\cdot\ln{2}\cdot\lim_{x\to 1^+}(x-1) \lt \lim_{x\to 1^+}\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} \lt \lim_{x\to 1^+}\left(\cos\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}\cdot(x-1)\right)
   $$

then:
$$
\cos{1}\cdot\ln{2}\cdot 0 \lt \lim_{x\to 1^+}\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} \lt \cos{1}\cdot\ln{2}\cdot 0
$$

finally:
$$
0 \lt \lim_{x\to 1^+}\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} \lt 0
$$

The indefinite integral is continuous in $(1,+\infty)$

By the **Squeeze Theorem** it follows that:
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^+}\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} = 0
$$

Because of the above limit that goes to $1^+$ as $x\to 1^+$ and the fact that $a$ was defined as a real number close to $1^+$, this leads to the fact that the integral's limit as $x\to b$ tends to a very small positive real number $\epsilon_0$ that approaches $0$. So:
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} = 0
$$

and $g(a)=\epsilon_0$

**Step 3**

Now since $g(x)=\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t}-x \, , \,\, x \in (1, +\infty)$ is continuous in $[a,b]\subset(1,+\infty)$
and the following hold:
$$
g(a)=\lim_{x\to 1^+}\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} - 1 = -1
$$

and

$$
\lim_{x\to b}g(x)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t} - x\right) = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\dfrac{x\cdot\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t}}{x} - 1\right)
$$

The following limit is indeterminate $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{x\cdot\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t}}{x}
$$

But the numerator and denominator are both continuous and differentiable functions, so applying $\mathcal{De\, L'H\hat{o}spital's}$ rule for indeterminate limits:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{x\cdot\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t}}{x}
&=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t}+x\cdot \cos{\dfrac{1}{x}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}}{1}
\\&=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t}+x\cdot \cos{\dfrac{1}{x}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}\right)
\\&=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\int_1^x{\cos{\frac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\frac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t}+\lim_{x\to +\infty}x\cos{\frac{1}{x}}\ln{\left(3-\frac{1}{x}\right)}
\\&=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\int_1^x{\cos{\frac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\frac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t}+\ln{3}\cdot\lim_{x\to +\infty}x \\&= +\infty
\end{aligned}
$$

Finally:
$$
g(b) = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\dfrac{x\cdot\int_1^x{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t}}{x}\right) - 1= +\infty -1 = +\infty
$$

This means that:
$$
g(a) \lt 0 \lt g(b)
$$
in addition to $g(x)$ being continuous in $[a,b]\subset(1,+\infty)$, then by $\mathcal{Bolzano's}$ theorem there is at least one $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that $g(\xi)=0$.

Which completes the proof as:

$$
\xi = \int_1^{\xi}{\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}\cdot\ln{\left(3-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}\ \mathcal{d}t}
$$

where $\xi > b > 1$